# How do I remove paint stripper that didn’t strip the paint?

Tags: bathroom

I used paint stripper in my bathroom, and applied two coats as stated.

The paint I was trying to strip was silk (I am not sure if that is relevant). Anyway, the paint stripper didn't work, but it has left a sticky tacky layer over the paint which I am now struggling to remove. I have tried using a scraper and tried wire wool. Are there any chemicals or cleaning products I could use to dissolve the stripper?

Comment: What is "silk"?

Comment: @isherwood - it's a finish sheen type [though doesn't describe the base, water or 'oil'] Finishes in the UK are described as going from full gloss through eggshell, silk or satin, matt, flat matt

Answer (score 5):

More stripper will remove stripper. Don't let it dry completely.

The container will have instructions on soak times. If you re-wet it each time before it is fully dry, you will eventually penetrate further into the paint. If the paint is truly impervious to the stripper, then one final coat, allowed to act for just 10 - 15 minutes or so should allow you to remove at least all the stripper itself.

Comment: Last stuff I used said to cover it with plastic and wait 12h but less than 24.